# With this code www.bodeind.is redirects to https but bodeinds.is Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead

Tags: nginx

I installed Let's Encrypt SSL for both www.bodeind.is and bodeind.is but when I enter bodeind.is in Firefox I get Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead. Any suggestion on how to correct this in the code below? When I enter www.bodeind.is everything works fine. When I test at ssllabs.com both www.bodeind.is and bodeind.is I get A rating.

```
I am running nginx on Ubuntu LTS 18.04
    #
    # Serve bodeind.is and www.bodeind.is
    #
    server {
            root /var/www/bodeind.is/html;
            index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
            server_name bodeind.is www.bodeind.is;
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            location / { 
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }
            location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            }
            location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
            }
            location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
            }
            location = /robots.txt {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
                allow all;
            }
            location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
            }
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bodeind.is/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bodeind.is/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }
    server {
        if ($host = www.bodeind.is) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
        if ($host = bodeind.is) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
            server_name bodeind.is www.bodeind.is;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for which domain(s) your TLS certificate applies. You'll need:

- `www.bodeind.is` or `*.bodeind.is`, and
- `bodeind.is`

Note that a certificate for `*.bodeind.is` does not match for host `bodeind.is`.

Also, make sure that you have *one* certificate. If you're requesting two different certificates, but are serving the domains from the same web server, then one certificate might overwrite the other.

Comment: When I look at the certificate it has - Common names: www.bodeind.is and 
Alternative names: bodeind.is www.bodeind.is. fullchain.pem has two certificates within that file. This is not a wild card certificate.